# How can I browserify every .js file in a directory with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I'm using Gulp to Browserify a specific file right now (`/src/js/main.js`) which will create a single bundle, but I want to watch the entire `src/js` directory and bundle each additional `.js` file that exists with `main.js`.

So if I had a directory with like:

`main.js`, `reset_password.js`, `auth_login.js`, it'd browserify each one separately.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('js', ['nunjucks'], function () {
  return (
    browserify(['./src/js/*.js'])
      .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        })
      .pipe(rename({
          suffix: '.min.js'
        }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
  );
});
```

Will throw an error that says:

> Cannot find module '/src/js/**.js'

It will work if I specify each file, but it won't do globbing. Can Browserify even watch an entire directory?

Answer (score 1):

You should call browserify by specifying only one unique file. This is the entry point to all the other files.

```
browserify(['./src/js/main.js'])
```

In this file do :

```
require('./reset_password')
```

And in reset_password, add something like :

```
module.exports = function(){.... // all the code is here
```